# Program menu shortcut not removed after Major Upgrade

Tags: wix

I have this component in my first version:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProgramMenuComponents" Directory="PROGRAMMENUFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Icon="icon.ico" Description="$(var.ProductName)" Target="[InstallFolder]$(var.MyApp.TargetFileName)" WorkingDirectory="InstallFolder"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="PROGRAMMENUFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyCo\MyApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct" Name="Uninstall $(var.ProductName)" Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" Description="Uninstalls $(var.ProductName)" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

I have removed the `UninstallProduct` element on my next version. Now when I install the first version, do a major upgrade to second version, then uninstall the shortcut remains. How do I ensure it's removed on major upgrade (even before uninstall). Major upgrade is scheduled `afterInstallExecute` (which must remain the case).

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallExecute"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing shortcut using RemoveFile element:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProgramMenuComponents" Directory="PROGRAMMENUFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Icon="icon.ico" Description="$(var.ProductName)" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.MyApp.TargetFileName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    <RemoveFile Id="RemoveOldUninstallShortcut" On="both" Name="[My shortcut file name].lnk" />
  </Component>
```